# Limits of sequences as continuous functions from certain topology on $\omega+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

Let T be a topological space, $p\in T$ and $u_n : \mathbb{N}\to T$.

(Should be a well known fact): The point $p$ is **a** limit of $u_n$ iff $u_n^{-1}V$ is open for every neighbourhood $V$ of $p$, with cofinite topology on $\mathbb{N}$

(My thought): Can we extend the domain space such that such pairs $(u_n, p)$ correspond to continuous functions?

Consider the set $\omega +1$ with the topology consisting of empty set and $C \cup \{\omega\}$ for every cofinite $C$ in $\omega$.
Then a continuous function corresponds to a convergent $u_n$ and a limit of it at $u_\omega$, as should be easy to see.

Is this correct? Does this topology have a standard name? Is this part of something more general? On an intuitive side, seems strange to force $\omega$ to be in every set with a "tail", since in other spaces like extended real line we don't do this, which makes me think there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. The space $\omega+1$ has the order topology wrt the natural (ordinal) order where $\omega$ has its usual order $0 < 1< 2< \ldots$ and $n < \omega$ for all $n \in \omega$. Because $\omega$ is the maximal element of the ordered set its basic neighbourhoods are o  the form $(x,\omega]$ for $x < \omega$, so $x \in \omega$ so of the form $(n, \omega] = \{m \in \omega\mid m > n\} \cup \{\omega\}$, precisely the cofinite neighbourhoods you describe (tails, essentially).

The order topology for points of $\omega$ itself is discrete: $0$ has $[0,1), [0,2), \ldots$ as basic neighbourhoods (being the minimum element)< so that comes down to essentially $\{0\} = [0,1)$, while $n>0$ has a neighbourhood of interval form $(n-1,n+1)=\{n\}$ (true in $\omega$, not in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q$ of course), so all points of $\omega$ are isolated points, and any function/sequence defined on them is automatically continuous, and the special neighbourhoods of $\omega$ ensure that $n \to u_n, \omega\to p$ is only continuous as a function from $\omega+1$ to $X$ iff $\lim_n u_n = p$ (also true if the limit is not unique, as can happen).

$\omega+1$ is just a standard ordinal space in the order topology, but experienced topologists often call it "the convergent sequence", it's a sort of prototypical space for that for these reasons. In fact a space with "(non-trivial) convergent sequences" is one that contains a homeomorphic copy of $\omega+1$, e.g. Some famous examples (like $\omega^* := \beta \omega\setminus \omega$ are examples of large compact space without convergent sequences.

It's called countable Fort space on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_space) and in the book "Counterexamples in Topology" by Steen and Seebach. Or you can call it the one-point compactification of the countable discrete space if you prefer.

Comment: Wouldn't the order topology be different than the one i gave? In mine {1} is not open but {1} = (0,2)

Comment: @Carlaismyname It's the only way to ensure that all convergent sequences $a_n \to p$ in a space $X$ correspond to a *continuous* function $n \to a_n, \omega\to p$ from $\Bbb N \cup \{\omega\}$ to $X$ in this way. If we give $\Bbb N$ the cofinite topology this won't be true.

Comment: Oh, i see, so the topology i gave would only work for constant sequences! (at least in metric spaces, might work sometimes in other spaces)

Comment: @Carlaismyname it only works for continuity of the function at $\onega$. The other points are the issue.